# Calculating row-wise student's t test between selected variables in a dataframe - R

Tags: r, dplyr, statistics, apply, purrr

I have a dataframe of individuals with different scores across different criteria, see example dataframe for 10 individuals each with 7 scores (A to G):

```
set.seed(123)
df <- data.frame(
  A = rnorm(10, mean = 0, sd = 1),
  B = rnorm(10, mean = 0, sd = 1),
  C = rnorm(10, mean = 0, sd = 1),
  D = rnorm(10, mean = 0, sd = 1),
  E = rnorm(10, mean = 0, sd = 1),
  F = rnorm(10, mean = 0, sd = 1),
  G = rnorm(10, mean = 0, sd = 1)
)

# OUTPUT
             A          B          C           D           E           F           G
1  -0.56047565  1.2240818 -1.0678237  0.42646422 -0.69470698  0.25331851  0.37963948
2  -0.23017749  0.3598138 -0.2179749 -0.29507148 -0.20791728 -0.02854676 -0.50232345
3   1.55870831  0.4007715 -1.0260044  0.89512566 -1.26539635 -0.04287046 -0.33320738
4   0.07050839  0.1106827 -0.7288912  0.87813349  2.16895597  1.36860228 -1.01857538
5   0.12928774 -0.5558411 -0.6250393  0.82158108  1.20796200 -0.22577099 -1.07179123
6   1.71506499  1.7869131 -1.6866933  0.68864025 -1.12310858  1.51647060  0.30352864
7   0.46091621  0.4978505  0.8377870  0.55391765 -0.40288484 -1.54875280  0.44820978
8  -1.26506123 -1.9666172  0.1533731 -0.06191171 -0.46665535  0.58461375  0.05300423
9  -0.68685285  0.7013559 -1.1381369 -0.30596266  0.77996512  0.12385424  0.92226747
10 -0.44566197 -0.4727914  1.2538149 -0.38047100 -0.08336907  0.21594157  2.05008469
```

I also have some of the variable names selected by users in two lists, clustering scores in two groups (does not have to include all columns and can be dynamic):

```
list1 <- c("B", "C", "D")
list2 <- c("A", "E", "G")
```

Now I need to perform a t.test() between the two group of scores for each individual and report the p value in a new column `pval`. I have managed to do this with a simple for loop, but it is slow and I'm sure there is a more elegant way to do this:

```
df$pval <- vector(mode = "list", length = dim(df)[1])

for (i in 1:dim(df)[1]) {
  df[i, "pval"] <- unlist(t.test(df[i, list1], df[i, list2])$p.value)
}
```

I would appreciate any help on how to do this with `map()` or `apply()` families of functions for examples.

*ChatGPT suggested `map2_dbl()` inside a `mutate()` but I could not make it work.*

Comment: Please specify the dimension of you real data. W.r.t. your for-loop approach: write `seq(nrow(df))` instead of `1:dim(df)[1]`. I think `unlist()` is not necessary. `*apply()`-functions are generally not faster.

Comment: How big is your data? does it have many individuals or does it have many criteria? If criteria, then the for-loop should work easily. If individuals, I would consider reshaping my data into long and use `data.table` etc

Comment: @Onyambu I have 20,000 individual with 1,000 columns. I can transform the data to long format and then group by the list1 or list2 but can't find a way to perform the t-test on those groups in that format

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To people who might run into the same problem, I found a very efficient way to do this in almost no time using `Rfast` package. The original for loop running for 10,0000 samples:

```
set.seed(123)
df <- data.frame(
  A = rnorm(10000, mean = 0, sd = 1),
  B = rnorm(10000, mean = 0, sd = 1),
  C = rnorm(10000, mean = 0, sd = 1),
  D = rnorm(10000, mean = 0, sd = 1),
  E = rnorm(10000, mean = 0, sd = 1),
  F = rnorm(10000, mean = 0, sd = 1),
  G = rnorm(10000, mean = 0, sd = 1)
)

list1 <- c("B", "C", "D")
list2 <- c("A", "E", "G")

df$pval <- vector(mode = "list", length = dim(df)[1])

system.time(for (i in 1:dim(df)[1]) {
  df[i, "pval"] <- unlist(t.test(df[i, list1], df[i, list2])$p.value)
})

#RUNTIME
   user  system elapsed 
  6.078   0.367   6.455
```

Now using `Rfast::ttests()` function:

```
df1 <- df[, list1] %>% as.matrix() %>% t()
df2 <- df[, list2] %>% as.matrix() %>% t()

system.time(Rfast::ttests(df1, df2))

#RUNTIME
   user  system elapsed 
  0.004   0.000   0.004
```

The for loop is ran in cpp instead of R making it much more efficient to run.

Comment: How does this solve the problem? It does not produce the required p-values

Answer (score 0):

you can certainly use parallel loops to speed up the operation. For example,

```
library(tidyverse)
library(foreach)
library(doSNOW)
library(parallel)

registerDoSNOW(cl<-makeCluster(detectCores-2))
result<- foreach (i = 1:dim(df)[1]) %dopar%{
    df[i, "pval"] <- unlist(t.test(df[i, list1], df[i, list2])$p.value)
  }
```

Comment: thank you for the suggestion but the server I'm running this on is uni-thread, can't do parallelisation.

Comment: @Meisam Oh, that's unfortunate. If parallel loop is not an option, you may think about chunking or data structure.

Answer (score 0):

Another way is to write a vectorized function. Note that you could make it faster by using Rcpp:

```
compute_pvals <- function(df, groups){
    
    nms <- setNames(rep(seq_along(groups), lengths(groups)),    unlist(groups))
    d <- df[names(nms)]
    a <- tapply(unlist(d), list(row(d), nms[col(d)]),
                 \(x)c(mean = mean(x), n = length(x)-1, v = var(x)/length(x)))
    
    ls1 <- do.call(rbind, a[,1])
    ls2 <- do.call(rbind, a[,2])
    vx <- ls1[,'v']
    vy <- ls2[,'v']
    stderr <- sqrt(vx + vy)
    dof <- stderr^4/(vx^2/ls1[,'n'] + vy^2/ls2[,'n'])
    tstat <- (ls1[,'mean'] - ls2[,'mean'])/stderr
    unname(2 * pt(-abs(tstat), dof))
}
```

comparing the two:

```
pvals(df, l)
[1] 0.5647411 0.3371633 0.9241260 0.7795392 0.8109423 0.9797499 0.2433040 0.9377242 0.4726551
[10] 0.7187993

for (i in 1:dim(df)[1]) {
    df[i, "pval"] <- t.test(df[i, list1], df[i, list2])$p.value
 }
df$pval
 [1] 0.5647411 0.3371633 0.9241260 0.7795392 0.8109423 0.9797499 0.2433040 0.9377242 0.4726551
[10] 0.7187993
```

---

Doing a benchmark:

```
pvals2 <- function(df, groups){
    n <- nrow(df)
    pvals <- numeric(n)
    list1 <- groups[[1]]
    list2 <- groups[[2]]
    for (i in seq(n))
    pvals[i] <- t.test(df[i, list1], df[i, list2])$p.value
    pvals
}
df1 <- data.frame(matrix(rnorm(1000000), 1000))
l1<-split(names(df1), sample(2,ncol(df1), T))

microbenchmark::microbenchmark(a=compute_pvals(df1,l1), b=pvals2(df1, l1), times=3, check='equal')
Unit: milliseconds
expr        min         lq       mean     median         uq       max neval
   a   234.7357   278.5149   308.8703   322.2942   345.9376   369.581     3
   b 12329.2909 14901.1254 15877.6509 17472.9598 17651.8309 17830.702     3
```